# Star/Wye electrical connection math symbol

Tags: macros, amsmath

I am writing lots of mathematics within electrical engineering, where I often need to specify which of two connection types I am talking about.

One is called Delta, specified with a triangle `$\Delta$`. The other is called Wye/Star, a three legged star with `$120\degree$` separated legs, like in the picture below.

[image]

What I wish for is a way to inline with the mathematics write `$\wye$` and get the depicted symbol the same way I get `$\Delta$`, but I am not very experienced with defining new symbols...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made one leg a bit thicker, in the manner of `\Delta`.

Works across math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating,stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\wye{\scalerel*{\stackengine{-1pt}{%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{30}{\rule{10pt}{.9pt}}\kern-1pt%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{-30}{\rule{10pt}{1.3pt}}}{%
  \rule{.9pt}{10pt}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}{\Delta}}
\begin{document}
$\Delta\wye
\scriptstyle\Delta\wye
\scriptscriptstyle\Delta\wye$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Merely changing the instances of `{30}` and `{-30}` to `{40}` and `{-40}` will change the aspect, while `scalerel` will take care of the scaling automatically:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Ti*k*Z? (Scalable line width added, great thanks to [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot)!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\wye}{\mathbin{\tikz[x=1ex,y=1ex]{\draw[line width=.1ex] (0,0)--(45:1)--++(-45:1) (45:1)--++(0,1);}}}
\begin{document}
$1\wye2$ {\Huge $1\wye2$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\wye}{\mathbin{\tikz[x=1ex,y=1ex]{\draw[line width=.1ex] (0,0)--(30:1)--++(-30:1) (30:1)--++(0,1);}}}
\begin{document}
$1\wye2$ {\Huge $1\wye2$}
\end{document}
```

[image]